# How to display only Hijri Year in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, stored-procedures

I wants to display only Hijri year. How to do that in SQL SERVER

> 1.When I try to convert Hijri to Gregorian with GETDATE(). It's showing output correctly

```
SELECT CONVERT(nchar, GETDATE(), 131)
output
------
18/10/1438  4:02:48:407PM     

SELECT CONVERT(nchar, '2016-10-02 12:00:00.000', 131)
Output
------
2016-10-02 12:00:00.000
```

> 2. I want to display Hijri year only like how we display only Gregorian year like below

```
select year(GETDATE())
output
------
2017

**Expecting output**
1438 (if I give Gregorian Date, it should display only Gregorian Year)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example**

```
select right(convert(nvarchar(10), getdate(), 131),4)
```

**Returns**

```
1438
```

You can cast the final result as INT if desired

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the better solution than substring

```
DECLARE @DateTime AS DATETIME
SET @DateTime=GETDATE()
SELECT 
    FORMAT(@DateTime,'yyyy','ar')AS [Gregorian date to Hijri date]

output
-------
1438
```

Comment: Plus 1 - I did not consider this because I love the features of Format(), but hate the performance.  That said, if OP is not doing record level processing, this is a nice solution

Comment: @JohnCappelletti can you give me more details about what you are saying?

Comment: Sure.  Format() is well known and documented to be a low performer.  Don't get me wrong, I love the functionality.  However, I would be hard pressed to use it against thousands of records.  I will use format() on final/compressed answersets or even declared variables or constants like GetDate() as above.

Comment: To be clear.  This is a perfectly valid solution (as are the other two).  The beauty of SO is that you get to pick the one that works best for you.

Comment: For example on 579,733 records Select Distinct Format(...) took 35 seconds while Select Distinct right(convert(... took less than 2 seconds.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti you are correct, I have millions of records. When I try to select top 10 records using format option, it tooks 3.37 min. and When I used your query it tooks 12 sec

Comment: Considering millions of records, perhaps a sub-query selecting distinct dates first.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `substring` like

```
select substring(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(),131), 7, 4)
```

Output :

```
1438
```